# How to load all key/value pairs in properties file

Tags: java, spring, properties, spring-boot

I'm trying to load all `key/value` pairs in my properties file.

One approach is that I load all the properties using `@Value` manually, but for that I should know all the keys.

I cannot do this, since property file may be changed in future to include more set of `key/value` pairs and I may need to modify `code` again to accommodate them.

Second approach is that I should some how load the properties file and Iterate over it to load all the `key/value` pairs without knowing the keys.

Say I have following properties file `sample.properties`

```
property_set.name="Database MySQL"
db.name=
db.url=
db.user=
db.passwd=

property_set.name="Database Oracle"
db.name=
db.url=
db.user=
db.passwd=
```

Here is what I'm trying to do

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value="classpath:sample.properties")
public class AppConfig {
    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Bean
    public void loadConfig(){
    //Can I some how iterate over the loaded sampe.properties and load all
    //key/value pair in Map<String,Map<String, String>>
    // say Map<"Database MySQL", Map<key,vale>>
    // I cannot get individual properties like env.getProperty("key"); 
    // since I may not know all the keys
}
}
```

Comment: Your current property file would load but only the last properties would be in there... As you stated it is a key/value thing, and the key has to be unique in your case it isn't unique.

Comment: @M.Deinum `property_set` itself is serving as a key, with set of keys underneath.
I'm not sure though how it would impact my implementation.

Comment: No it isn't that isn't how property files work. db.name will override db.name. Regardless what the line before said.

Comment: You are right, how about if I make keys unique for every set.
say `db.name.ms` , `db.name.or` . All I want is to load them all without bothering about keys.

Answer (score 7):

Spring stores all properties in `Environment`.
`Environment` contains collection of `PropertySource`. Every `PropertySource` contains properties from specific source. There are system properties, and java environment properties and many other. Properties from you file will be there as well.

Any source has own name. In your case automatically generated name will be look like *`"class path resource [sample.properties]"`*. As you see, the name is not so convenient. So lets set more convenient name:

```
@PropertySource(value="classpath:sample.properties", name="sample.props")
```

Now you can get source by this name:

```
AbstractEnvironment ae = (AbstractEnvironment)env;
org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource source =
                              ae.getPropertySources().get("sample.props");
Properties props = (Properties)source.getSource();
```

Note that I specified full name of `PropertySource` class, to avoid conflict with @PropertySource annotation class. After that, you can work with properties. For example output them to console:

```
for(Object key : props.keySet()){
   System.out.println(props.get(key));
}
```

Comment: This worked beautifully for me... One up for you Chieftain!

Comment: from where "env" coming from? When I use @Autowired Environment env getting null and my package is also correct

Answer (score 1):

You can `autowire` in an [EnumerablePropertySource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/EnumerablePropertySource.html) which contains the method `getPropertyNames()`

Answer (score 0):

you can look up the class  `Properties`  in the jdk api  and use the method `load(InputStream inStream)`

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream("your properties location");
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(in);
```

ps: prop is subClass of HashTable and don't forget to close stream

Comment: `@PropertySource` will take care of this. Besides this isn't the `spring` way to do it.