# How to read key from value of resource bundle/properties file

Tags: java, bundle, properties-file

I have *messages.properties* bundle file which contains labels in key, value pair like

```
meta.enum.ShipmentStatus.Loaded=Loaded
```

But I want read key from value i.e. from user/client view I get "Loaded" value and I want read key of that value i.e. "meta.enum.ShipmentStatus.Loaded".

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can read keys by loading all keys and values into a map. If so,

```
public <K, V> Stream<K> keys(Map<K, V> map, V value) {
return map
  .entrySet()
  .stream()
  .filter(entry -> value.equals(entry.getValue()))
  .map(Map.Entry::getKey); }
```

can
return the keys for the value.
But, if you are using Spring look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34655571/11813364

Comment: thank @Aytac for your inputs but this solution will work when properties file contains very limited labels and in my case there are more than 10000 labels present. So I can't iterate all those records.